# How obtain the Context object into a class extenging Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-resources, android-context

I am pretty new new in Android and I am finding some dificulties to do the following thing related to the Context.

So I have an utility class that contain an utility method that create and return a **Bitmap** image, this is the code of my class:

```
public class ImgUtility {

    /**
     * Method that create the images related to the difficulty of a recepy
     * @param context
     * @param difficulty that represent the number of chef_hat_ok into the final image
     * @return a Bitmap representing the difficult of a recepy
     */
    public static Bitmap createRankingImg(Context context, int difficulty) {

        // Create a Bitmap image starting from the star.png into the "/res/drawable/" directory:
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.chef_hat_ok);


        // Create a new image bitmap having width to hold 5 star.png image:
        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth() * 5, myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        /* Attach a brand new canvas to this new Bitmap.
           The Canvas class holds the "draw" calls. To draw something, you need 4 basic components:
           1) a Bitmap to hold the pixels.
           2) a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap).
           3) a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap).
           4) a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing).
         */
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

        // Draw the image bitmap into the cavas:
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, null);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getWidth() * 2, 0, null);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getWidth() * 3, 0, null);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getWidth() * 4, 0, null);

        return tempBitmap;

    }

}
```

As you can see this class contains the **createRankingImg()** that take the **Context** object as parameter and use it to create an image. This object is used to retrieve an image from the resources (into the **BitmapFactory.decodeResource()** method). What exactly represent the Context object into an Android application?

I know that to obtain the **context** into an activity class I can use the **getResources()** method.

My problem is that I have to obtain the context into a class that exetends Fragment.

I have something like this:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    .......................................................................
    .......................................................................
    .......................................................................

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        .....................................................................
        .....................................................................
        .....................................................................

        switch (mPageNumber + 1) {

            case 1:
                imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carbonara);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.carbonara));

                ImageView difficultyContainerImageView1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.difficultyContainer);

                difficultyContainerImageView1.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),     ImgUtility.createRankingImg(getApplicationContext(), 3)));

                break;

        .....................................................................
        .....................................................................
        .....................................................................

        }

        return rootView;
}
```

My problem is that when in the previous fragment class I call the method:

```
ImgUtility.createRankingImg(getResources(), 3)
```

passing to it the **getResources()** output (that I thinked give me the **Context**, the IDE give me the following error message:

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.content.res.Resources',
>   required: 'android.content.Context'

So it seems to me that into a class that extends a **Fragment** and not an **Activity** the **getResources()** method return a **Resources** object instead a **Context** object (as done into an Activity class). Is it true? Why?

**How can I obtain the Context inside a class that extends Fragment? And what exactly represent the Context in an Android app? What am I missing? How can I sole this issue?**

Comment: It say to me "Cannot restolve getActivity()"? Why?

Comment: `getActivity()` is defined in `Fragment` so apparently you're not in a `Fragment` or there's a typo or something.

Answer (score 0):

Create an initial function that takes Context as a parameter so you can pass the context object from the activity class.

Comment: Fragment constructors should take no arguments.